# React native split one image to multiple parts

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-image

I have one image now I want to split that one image into three parts.

How can I do it in React-native? I've tried different packages but not getting appropriate result which I exactly need in my app.

I am attaching image and output that's needed for my requirements.
After splitting image I need three different image.

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this?

Comment: @SuhailRifky

Did you find any solutions ??